# Should I define separate module for every file in my Guile project?

Tags: module, scheme, guile

Let me explain my problem by comparison. In Common Lisp I could split package definitions to several files, it was enough to declare in each of them that it's `in-package` and `load` them.

However in Guile Scheme it looks like I should `define-module`, separate for each file? Well I still can `load` some files like in CL and it looks like working, `define-modules` seems not limited to a single file it is located in like in CL, but I get warnings about undefined names (those that are defined in `load`ed files), so it gives me feeling that it's not what Guile expects. Is there (1) some way of splitting module across several files like in CL, or (2) should I stick to `use-module` autoload feature and `define-module` for each file separatelly?

Comment: The second option: use several `define-module` and `use-module` possibly `re-export` stuff defined in submodules.

Comment: @amirouche If you post it as an answer, I'm happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed in Guile you can `load` inside a `define-module` but it will report unbound variable at compile time.

The idiomatic way is the `define-module` in every file:

```
;; in earth-software-system.scm
(define-module (earth-software-system))

(use-modules (earth-software-system bullet-train))
(use-modules (srfi srfi-9))

(re-export bullet-train) ;; possibly re-exporting imported bindings

...
```

Then in `earth-software-system/bullet-train.scm` you can have:

```
;; in earth-software-system/bullet-train.scm
(define-module (earth-software-system bullet-train))

(use-modules (srfi srfi-9))

(define-public bullet-train 42)

...
```

Mind the fact that `define-public` and a single import per `use-modules` is not widespread. Here is an example from GNU Guix project that rely on `define-module` to import and export:

```
(define-module (guix cpio)
  #:use-module ((guix build utils) #:select (dump-port))
  #:use-module (srfi srfi-9)
  #:use-module (srfi srfi-11)
  #:use-module (rnrs bytevectors)
  #:use-module (rnrs io ports)
  #:use-module (ice-9 match)
  #:export (cpio-header?
            make-cpio-header
            file->cpio-header
            file->cpio-header*
            write-cpio-header
            read-cpio-header

            write-cpio-archive))
```

Also nowadays I prefer the `import` form which is more easy to the mind that `use-modules`:

```
;; in earth-software-system.scm
(define-module (earth-software-system))

(import (prefix (earth-software-system bullet-train) 'bt:)
(import (srfi srfi-9))

(re-export bt:bullet-train) ;; possibly re-exporting imported bindings

...
```

The prefix syntax is also more easy to the mind than the equivalent using `use-modules`. This is inspired from R6RS `library` form and R7RS `define-library` form. I do not recommend to use `library` form in Guile since it doesn't report lines correctly.

GNU Guile allow to import forms even if they are not exported using the [`@@` syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Using-Guile-Modules.html#index-_0040_0040) for instance to test some tricky behavior.

You might replace `load` with [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Local-Inclusion.html#index-include) but I never used it in Guile